# Drawcall not reduced when prefabs are instantiated from AB file after sprites are packed into atlas?

Tags: unity-game-engine, sprite, sprite-sheet

I am using Unity 2021.3 LTS, I have 3 sprites where are packed into a sprite atlas, and I created 3 simple prefabs based on each sprites.

1. When I drag 3 sprites or 3 prefabs into Hierarchy and press Play, the batching number is 1.

Then I created assets bundles, 3 ab files for 3 prefabs, 1 ab file for sprites and atlas.
2. If I create 3 empty gameobjects with code during runtime, add SpriteRenderer and give them sprites which are gotten with atlas.GetSprite(), and the atlas is loaded from the AB file, the batching number is still 1.

3. But if I directly instantiate 3 prefabs which are first loaded from the AB file during runtime, the batching number is 3, which seems the sprites of the prefabs are not referened by the atlas anymore. I am sure that the dependent atlas and sprites AB file was loaded prior to the loading of the prefabs.

I have made many tests and searchs on the Internet, but still can't find any clue. For now, I'm trying 3rd party sprite packing tool, but I don't think that will work either.

Thank you very much for reading this, please help.

Answer (score 0):

When Instantiating, Unity seems to ignore dynamic batching, have you tried disabling and enabling again the Game Objects after Instantiate ?

```
void BatchSprites()
{
     gameObject.SetActive(false);
     gameObject.SetActive(true);
}
```

Comment: hi Yuris, I just tried disabling and enabling the gameobject, it didn't work, but it looks like it's not the prefab or assets bundle which made the difference, somehow the sprite renderer looks suspicious, so yes, I think it's a dynamic batching issue like you said. Thank you.